# Elasticsearch - Get entire documents that Match nested field & Max value of another field

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, match, aggregation

Given the following mapping and documents in Elasticsearch, how would I get the max of a set of nested documents that match a certain condition? For instance, how would I get only the documents that their set of vehicles matching "X Motors" and "X Motors" is the max model in the set?

Mapping:

```
    PUT /drivers

{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "driver": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "last_name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "vehicle": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "make": {
                                "type": "text"
                            },
                            "model": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documents:

```
PUT /drivers/_doc/1
{
    "driver": {
        "last_name": "lastName1",
        "vehicle": [
            {
                "make": "X Motors",
                "model": 2005
            },
            {
                "make": "Y Motors",
                "model": 2000
            }
        ]
    }
}

PUT /drivers/_doc/2
{
    "driver": {
        "last_name": "lastName2",
        "vehicle": [
            {
                "make": "X Motors",
                "model": 1992
            },
            {
                "make": "Y Motors",
                "model": 2002
            }
        ]
    }
}

PUT /drivers/_doc/3

{
    "driver": {
        "last_name": "lastName3",
        "vehicle": [
            {
                "make": "X Motors",
                "model": 2019
            },
            {
                "make": "Y Motors",
                "model": 2020
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In this case, I want to get the entire document with ID: 1,
Because it's the only document that in its vehicle set contains an object with max vehicle.driver.model & also matching vehicle.driver.make of "X Motors".

Thanks!

Comment: How document 1 have max `vehicle.driver.model`  ?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear.
I'll try to explain myself better.

I'm trying to fetch all of the documents that inside their own vehicle set,
the object with the maximum model, is matching make of "X Motors".

The first document is the only one that answers to those conditions

    "vehicle": [
                {
                    "make": "X Motors",
                    "model": 2005
                },
                {
                    "make": "Y Motors",
                    "model": 2000
                }
            ]

2005 is the max model, and the make is X Motors.

Answer (score 0):

The below query matches all documents that match for `"driver.vehicle.make":"X Motors"` and contains an object with the max `driver.vehicle.model`

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "driver.vehicle.model": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "driver.vehicle"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "size":1,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "driver.vehicle",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "driver.vehicle.make": "X Motors"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The search result will be -

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66156348",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "driver": {
            "last_name": "lastName3",
            "vehicle": [
              {
                "make": "X Motors",
                "model": 2019
              },
              {
                "make": "Y Motors",
                "model": 2020
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "sort": [
          2020
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Sorry for being not clear.
I'll try to explain myself better.

I'm trying to fetch all of the documents that inside their own vehicle set,
the object with the maximum model, is matching make of "X Motors".

The first document is the only one that answers to those conditions

    "vehicle": [
                {
                    "make": "X Motors",
                    "model": 2005
                },
                {
                    "make": "Y Motors",
                    "model": 2000
                }
            ]

2005 is the max model, and the make is X Motors.

Comment: @OrielBasson now it is clear. And, are you sure that `driver` is of nested type ?

Comment: driver is the parent object, my mapping is wrong?